# classification of algebraic space curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm reading an Mumford's article "Further pathologies in algebraic geometry, the second exemple about the chacarteristic map".

And i want to know why un curve of degre 14 is contained in a UNIQUE cubic surface?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a curve of degree $14$, it's a curve in a particular linear system $D$ (which I don't remember right now). Another cubic would intersect the given one in $3H$, and the difference $3H-D$ is not effective.